# Date/Timestamp is reset to now() when saving?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to explain my issue once more this time using a example as well.

I have a "calendars" table with following fields:

```
date_from (TIMESTAMP)
date_to (TIMESTAMP)
dt (DATE)
status (INT)
```

Here you see the table with some entries

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | date_from           | date_to             | dt           | status |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 | 2017-01-10 00:00:00 | 2017-01-10   | 1      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2  | 2017-01-11 00:00:00 | 2017-01-11 00:00:00 | 2017-01-11   | 1      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3  | 2017-01-12 00:00:00 | 2017-01-12 00:00:00 | 2017-01-12   | 1      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And here it is what im trying to do:

```
$dates = ['2017-01-10', '2017-01-11', '2017-01-12'];
foreach($dates as $date){
    $d = Calendar::query()->where('dt', $date)->first();
    $d->status = 2; //Booked
    $d->save();
}
```

When saving these models, `date_from` and `date_to` are set to current time/now(), any suggestion why this is happening?

Here is my migration file:

```
Schema::create('calendars', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->timestamp('date_from');
    $table->timestamp('date_to');
    $table->date('dt')->nullable();
    $table->tinyInteger('status')->default('1');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

And here is my model:

```
class Calendar extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'date_from',
        'date_to',
        'status'
    ];

    protected $table = 'calendars';
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $dates = ['date_from', 'date_to', 'dt'];
}
```

Thanks in advance for looking into this.

Comment: would you clarify by an example ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy take a new look on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Check in the database for that field you didn't set default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.
```

Comment: Somehow the migration created the field with 

date_from timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP